# Google Identity Toolkit returns CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android, google-identity-toolkit

I'm trying to Build Google+ Sign In On Android Device using Google Identity Toolkit , I followed the Quick Start Guide on https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/ , but I'm repeatedly getting the following error.

`"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "invalid",
"message": "CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND"
}
],
"code": 400,
"message": "CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND"
}
}`

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Could you please repost your question to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-identity-toolkit, which enables identity toolkit engineers to contact you directly?

Answer (score 23):

May be you are using firebase email/password authentication service or some other authentication service provided by firebase and haven't enabled it yet from the firebase console **Authentication** tab.

I have resolved this sort of issue in that way.

[image]

Comment: In my case it was exactly what you pointed out, thank you!

Comment: I was using `signInWithCustomToken()`, and just visiting the authentication page in firebase console and pressing on "Get Started" button was sufficient for me.

Comment: I had been stuck on this issue too! Turns out I didn't even enable authentication in the first place. What a facepalm!

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to setup this config: `./google-services.json`

As explained here: https://docs.expo.io/guides/setup-native-firebase/#android

Answer (score 0):

I was using Firebase auth .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) and faced that issue. In my case, just like Kasunaz aforementioned, enabling Email/Password sign-in method solved the issue.